# put two button in parallel with the same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following buttons and I want them to be in parallel with the same height

I try to put them on span and give them the same height but its not working,
the remove file button is bigger than the choose file and not in parallel .

```
            <span>
                <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;height: 25px " id="RemoveFile">Remove File</button>
                <input onchange="fileOnchange(this)" style="height: 25px"  type="file"  />
            </span>
```

Comment: can u provide fiddle???

Comment: They look the same height to me on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eeT6Q/

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla- jsfiddle.net/eeT6Q :)

Comment: @Jay-they dont I've looked at the filddle and the remove file is bigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that can help you. Change them according to your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/sankalpsri/8Q38B/
**HTML**

```
<span>
    <button type="button" id="RemoveFile">Remove File</button>
    <input onchange="fileOnchange(this)"  class="custom-file-input" type="file"  />
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
input, button{
    height: 31px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;

}
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Select some files';
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just increase the font size of input file

```
            <span>
            <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;height: 25px " id="RemoveFile">Remove File</button>
            <input onchange="fileOnchange(this)" style="height: 25px; font-size:15.6px;"  type="file"  />
            </span>
```

here is the fiddle of what u expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/eeT6Q/3/

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
<span>
                <button type="button" style="display: inline-block; height:23px; vertical-align:top; " id="RemoveFile">Remove File</button>
                <input onchange="fileOnchange(this)" style="height: 25px"  type="file"  />
            </span>
```